# Aggregate daily data by month and an additional column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I've got a DataFrame storing daily-based data which is as below:

```
   Date        Product Number  Description        Revenue
2010-01-04       4219-057       Product A        39.299999    
2010-01-04       4219-056       Product A        39.520000
2010-01-04       4219-100       Product B        39.520000
2010-01-04       4219-056       Product A        39.520000
2010-01-05       4219-059       Product A        39.520000
2010-01-05       4219-056       Product A        39.520000
2010-01-05       4219-056       Product B        39.520000
2010-02-08       4219-123       Product A        39.520000
2010-02-08       4219-345       Product A        39.520000
2010-02-08       4219-456       Product B        39.520000
2010-02-08       4219-567       Product C        39.520000
2010-02-08       4219-789       Product D        39.520000
```

(Product number is just to give an idea) 
What I intend to do is to merge it into Monthly-based data.
Something like:

```
Date        Description        Revenue
2010-01-01    Product A        157.85000 (Sum of all Product A in Month 01)    
              Product B        79.040000
              Product C        00.000000
              Product D        00.000000
2010-02-01    Product A        39.299999 (Sum of all Product A in Month 02)   
              Product B        39.520000
              Product C        39.520000
              Product D        39.520000
```

The problem is I have 500+ products for every month

I am new to python and don't know how to implement it. Currently, I am using

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
%matplotlib inline

data.groupby(['DATE','REVENUE']).sum().unstack()
```

but not grouping it with the Products.

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert "Date" to `datetime`, then use `groupby` and `sum`:

```
# Do this first, if necessary.
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], errors='coerce')

(df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='MS'), 'Description'])['Revenue']
   .sum()
   .reset_index())

        Date Description     Revenue
0 2010-01-01           A  197.379999
1 2010-01-01           B   79.040000
2 2010-02-01           A   79.040000
3 2010-02-01           B   39.520000
4 2010-02-01           C   39.520000
5 2010-02-01           D   39.520000
```

The fréquency "MS" specifies to group on dates and set the offset to the start of each month.

Comment: This code shows me the data for only one month. Also, the dates have been changed with 1970-01-01 which is not my current dates.

Comment: @VishveshShah As you can see, this works for me and produces the output as expected. You'll either need to provide additional data for debugging or tinker with it a bit yourself.

Comment: @VishveshShah - What is your pandas version? This works for me on 0.24. If you have an older version, try upgrading and running again.

Comment: Mine is the same. '0.24.2'
I will look into the code if there is any other problem. Thanks!

Comment: My date is 2017-07-29 but is converted as 1970-01-01 00:00:00.020170729. Is there any way I can make the correction in python?

Comment: @VishveshShah Try `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d', errors='coerce')` as the first statement.

Comment: This does not work as described... as stated by the original asker it converts the dates to a different year altogether. In my case the first example changed from 2019-02-13 to 2015-01-01. This happens after the group by, not the date conversion.

Answer (score -1):

This is a bit of a workaround but if you simply create a 'Month_Year' variable in a new column using -

```
df['Month_Year'] = df['Date'].dt.to_period('M')
```

You can then groupby that column and aggregate as needed, like so -

```
df_agg = df.groupby(["Month_Year", "Description"])['Revenue'].sum().reset_index()
```